# regex to extract first n digits and all letters

Tags: r, regex

I have this character vector

```
[1] "0204Aug"    "30Aug01Sep"    "0608Sep"   "2022Sep"    "2729Sep"    "1113Oct"    "2527Oct"    "0103Nov"    "1517Nov"    "29Nov01Dec"
```

and for each element I want to extract the start date and the end date (in 2 separate vectors or a data.frame, even better if already in a Date format).

I was able to get the end date but I would like to do it using a regex and str_extract from `stringr`

```
str_sub(dates_raw, 3, 8)
```

For the start date I got this regex to match the first 2 digits with a look ahead

```
\d{2}(?=\d{2})
```

and this to match the letters

```
[A-z]{3}
[A-z]{3}$
```

but when I try to combine them in a single regex I get nothing

```
\d{2}(?=\d{2})[A-z]
> Your regular expression does not match the subject string.
```

*desired Output*:

```
[1] "02 Aug"    "30 Aug"    "06 Sep"
[1] "04 Aug"    "01 Sep"    "08 Sep"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `str_replace`

```
library(tidyverse)
ss %>%
    str_replace("([\\d+]{2})([\\d+]{2})([A-Za-z]{3})", "\\1\\3\\2\\3") %>%
    str_split("(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=\\d)") %>%
    map(~setNames(as.Date(.x, format = "%d%b"), c("start", "end")))
#[[1]]
#       start          end
#"2019-08-02" "2019-08-04"
#
#[[2]]
#       start          end
#"2019-08-30" "2019-09-01"
#
#[[3]]
#       start          end
#"2019-09-06" "2019-09-08"
#
#[[4]]
#       start          end
#"2019-09-20" "2019-09-22"
#
#[[5]]
#       start          end
#"2019-09-27" "2019-09-29"
#
#[[6]]
#       start          end
#"2019-10-11" "2019-10-13"
#
#[[7]]
#       start          end
#"2019-10-25" "2019-10-27"
#
#[[8]]
#       start          end
#"2019-11-01" "2019-11-03"
#
#[[9]]
#       start          end
#"2019-11-15" "2019-11-17"
#
#[[10]]
#       start          end
#"2019-11-29" "2019-12-01"
```

This returns a `list` of `Date` objects. If you prefer a `list` of `character` strings remove the `as.Date` line.

---

### Sample data

```
ss <- c("0204Aug",    "30Aug01Sep",    "0608Sep",   "2022Sep",    "2729Sep",    "1113Oct",    "2527Oct",    "0103Nov",    "1517Nov",    "29Nov01Dec")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the logic here is too complex for a regex alone, since it will need to reuse the Month value in some, but not all, instances. Luckily, we can do a bit more than that in R.

Here, we loop through the vector of dates and use regex to extract all day values and all month values. We can then paste them back together to get the proper date values.

```
dates <- c("0204Aug", "30Aug01Sep", "0608Sep", "2022Sep", "2729Sep", "1113Oct", "2527Oct", "0103Nov", "1517Nov", "29Nov01Dec")

library(stringr)
lapply(dates, function(date) {
    days = str_match(date, '([0-9]{2}).*([0-9]{2})')[,-1]
    month = str_match(date, '([A-z]{3})[0-9]*([A-z]{3})?')[,-1]
    month = na.omit(month)
    dates = paste(days, month)
})

[[1]]
[1] "02 Aug" "04 Aug"

[[2]]
[1] "30 Aug" "01 Sep"

[[3]]
[1] "06 Sep" "08 Sep"

[[4]]
[1] "20 Sep" "22 Sep"

[[5]]
[1] "27 Sep" "29 Sep"

[[6]]
[1] "11 Oct" "13 Oct"

[[7]]
[1] "25 Oct" "27 Oct"

[[8]]
[1] "01 Nov" "03 Nov"

[[9]]
[1] "15 Nov" "17 Nov"

[[10]]
[1] "29 Nov" "01 Dec"
```

`stringr::str_match` lets us supply multiple capturing groups with parentheses, which let us extract 2 sets of double numbers or 2 sets of month style strings from each item. It returns a dataframe, with the match in the first column (which we drop since we only want the capuring groups) and the 2 capturing groups in the next 2.

In the case of the Month values, we make the second capturing group optional with the `?`, which will return `NA` if it's not found. We drop the `NA`s with `na.omit`, then make use of `paste`'s property of repeating the shorter vector when given 2 vectors of unequal length to repeat the month if only one is found.

Comment: this is why i will never fully understand regex  thanks for the explanation